# Middleware with except option for multi methods

Tags: php, laravel

I need use `except` for `auth` middleware. Documentation shows this example:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('subscribed')->except('store');
}
```

For only one method, this works:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth')->except('method1');
}
```

But how to do this for multi methods?

I tried:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth')->except('method1');
    $this->middleware('auth')->except('method2');
}
```

and this not works, then I found in tutorial (which is not official), this syntax:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except'=>['method1','method2']]);
}
```

My question is: why this (multiple `except` case) isn't described in official documentation? at least i can't found anything, or I missunderstood something ?

Comment: "why this (multiple except case) isn't described in official documentation?" - I don't think this is a question for Stackoverflow; we don't write the documentation. Perhaps this would be better as an issue raised on the Laravel github?

Comment: You can now use `$this->middleware('auth', ['method1', 'method2']);`

Comment: You can use `$this->middleware('auth')->except(['method1', 'method2']);` as well.

Comment: @TimLewis - Probably you are right, though, now I understand that this syntax really not described there and this isn't my fault. )) thanks

Comment: @Styx - Your syntax seems more clean than I found. Thanks

Comment: No worries :) Just remember that Laravel is open source, and you're welcome to make a contribution to the documentation (or at the very least a suggestion on something missing that should be there). I bet it would be appreciated!

Comment: @OTAR You can even omit square braces (array) and just pass them as multiple parameters. If you peek at this method PHPDoc, it states there `@param  array|string|dynamic`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following syntax:

```
$this->middleware('auth')->except(['method1', 'method2']);
```